# how to add sort direction with linq for sql?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sorting

Suppose I have linq expression q, then I want to add a sort to this query:

```
q = q.OrderBy(p => p.Total);
```

but for sort, there is desc/asc option for SQL,  how to add it in above linq expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) will sort by ascending order, for descending, use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx):

```
q = q.OrderByDescending(p => p.Total);
```

And if you want to order by multiple columns, use the [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx), and [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx) methods.

```
q = q.OrderBy(p => p.Col1).ThenByDescending(p => p.Col2);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's another method for that, `OrderByDescending`

A bit of an overkill, probably, but if you really want to be able to pass a parameter indicating sort order, you could create an extension method:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TResult> OrderBy<TResult,TKey>(this IEnumerable<TResult> source, Func<TResult, TKey> keySelector, bool ascending)
{
   Func<Func<TResult, TKey>, IOrderedEnumerable<TResult>> orderMethod = source.OrderBy;

   if(!ascending)
      orderMethod = source.OrderByDescending;

   return orderMethod.Invoke(keySelector);
}
```

That way you'd be able to do

```
bool ascending = true;
list.OrderBy(item => item.Name, ascending);
```